# Definite assignment of variables

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8, initialization

This is with reference to definite assignment of variables where the compiler checks for Initializer errors for local variable `k`.

```
void flow(boolean flag) {
    int k;
    if (flag)
        k = 3;
    if (!flag)
        k = 4;
    System.out.println(k); 
}
```

This piece of code throws a compile error:

> `k` needs to be initialized.

In the below scenario, no matter what value of the `flag` variable, the value of the `k` variable will be assigned. Is this compile error here justified?

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough to know you've checked both flag conditions if you don't use an `else`. Use an `else`.

Comment: A better question is, is this code justified? Why would you explicitly check both sides of a boolean?

Comment: A far better version would be: `final int k = flag ? 3 : 4;` One line instead of five, better to understand and as a plus the variable `k` is immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the compiler doesn't check all the possible values of the fields which are not final (`flag` here).

Compiler will only be able analyze compile-time constants and confirm if local variable will be initialized or not.

More on this in Java Language Specification : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html

Consider two more variations of the same method ...

Here, even though compiler knows the value of flag, **it throws compiler error** for the variable k.

```
void flow() {
    boolean flag = false;
    int k;
    if (flag)
        k = 3;
    if (!flag)
        k = 4;
    System.out.println(k); 
}
```

---

Here as flag is a compile-time constant, compiler can calculate the value of variable k and **hence NO compile errors**.

```
void flow() {
    final boolean flag = false;
    int k;
    if (flag)
        k = 3;
    if (!flag)
        k = 4;
    System.out.println(k); 
}
```

Comment: This does clear my doubt . The compile time constant thing was what i was primarily looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true that the variable `k` will be initialized regardless of its state. However, because the two `if` conditions are not related to one another hence the compiler cannot guarantee that the variable `k` would have been initialized by the time control gets to the `println` method invocation.

I am assuming you know the fix to the problem at hand but if that's not the case, you'll just need to remove the second `if` statement and then chain an  `else` block onto the first `if` statement.

Comment: This is a code i came across while reading a tutorial , i believe the solution is compile time constants and yes i do know the code fix to this :) thanks